# Interpret an interpolated variable as a literal string in Perl regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, perl

I am using `perl` to colorize a matched string

```
MATCH=aaa
printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" | perl -pe "s/($MATCH)/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g"
```

This works well until I try to match a string containing special characters, e.g.

```
MATCH=/dev/
printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" | perl -pe "s/($MATCH)/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g"
```

The reason is, when `bash` substitutes `$MATCH`, perl gets the following expression:

```
perl -pe "s/(/dev/)/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g"
```

I would need to backslash those `/` to make it work, i.e.

```
MATCH=\/dev\/
printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" | perl -pe "s/($MATCH)/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g"
```

But I don't know what `MATCH` will contain. It could be anything, `+` or `(`. Is there a way to tell `perl` to treat the characters literally, not as an expression?

## UPDATE:

Using solution suggested by `Joseph R.` gives following error:

```
MATCH=/dev/
printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" | perl -pe "s/\Q($MATCH)\E/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g"
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ")\"
(Missing operator before \?)
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/\Q(/dev/)"
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

## UPDATE2:

now I don't get any error, but there seems to be no match (there is no coloring):

```
# MATCH=/dev/ ; printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" | perl -pe 's/(\Q$ENV{MATCH}\E)/\e[1;31m\1\e[0m/g'
aaa
/dev/aaa
ccc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use Perl's `quotemeta` operator with single quotes:

```
export MATCH=...
... | perl -pe 's/(\Q$ENV{MATCH}\E)/...
```

Anything between `\Q` and `\E` (or till the end of the regex if no `\E` is supplied) is considered as-is with no special meaning attached to metacharacters.

Equivalently:

```
export MATCH=...
... | perl -pe '$sane=quotemeta $ENV{MATCH};s/($sane)/...
```

**Update**

Here's how it can be done **without `export`**:

```
MATCH=/dev/
printf "aaa\n/dev/aaa\nccc\n" \
 | perl -pe "\$sane=quotemeta q{$MATCH};s/(\$sane)/\e[1;31m\$1\e[0m/g"
```

Note that your code had a mistake. You can't use a backreference (`\1`) in the replacement pattern of a `s///`, you need to use the match variable instead (`$1`), which I have used as `\$1` here, to avoid the shell interpolating `$1` because of the soft quotes.

In general, if you're doing a lot of colorizing work with Perl, I would suggest using a module to handle terminal idiosyncrasies for you. Check out [Term::ANSIColor](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html) for example.

Comment: I get an error. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @MartinVegter Sorry, my bad. The `quotemeta` tricks works with interpolated variables only. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: please see my update2

Comment: @MartinVegter As I put in my edit, you need to `export MATCH` for it to be visible from within the Perl sub-process. In the previous case, the current shell was handling the substitution so it was able to see `MATCH` without an `export`.

Comment: exporting the variable seems not very elegant way to do it. I am using the expression inside a bash script and my variable is `$1`. Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: Is there another way to do it, without the `export` of the variable ? For some reason, this approach seems ugly to me.

Comment: @MartinVegter Please see if this helps.

Comment: could you please modify the last example so that I can copy/paste it to my commandline and test it? I don't know what I should substitute for the `...` in your example.

Comment: @MartinVegter You should substitute whatever you were piping to `perl -pe` in your original script.

Comment: that does not work. Why can't you write the whole command, so that I can copy/paste it to see if it works?

Comment: @MartinVegter Please see the edit.

Comment: Exporting a variable seems perfectly fine in this case, especially since it is inside a script, as you say. When the script finishes, the variable is gone anyway. (But probably your goal could be reached easier with `grep --color`?)

Comment: @Joseph R. - thanks that works great now. I just realized, I will need to match either `MATCH1` or `MATCH2`. I have tried modifying your expression to add `($MATCH1|$MATCH2)` but that does not work. Would you have any suggestion how to test for two or more variables?

Comment: @MartinVegter Make sure you're not including the `|` inside your `quotemeta`, otherwise it loses its meaning.